# Angular async signal state management

Tags: angular, frontend, state, signals, side-effects

I'm working on a medium sized Angular app and this is the situation:

1. The user gets auth'd and data A is requested. Once/if that comes through, data B must be requested. Data A is global. Data B is specific to the page, but still has to be persistant.
2. Data A includes the default/available date range. User must be able to input date range.

Component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-example',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  templateUrl: './example.component.html',
})
export class ExampleComponent {
  myService = inject(MyServiceService);

  waitForA = effect(
    () => this.myService.availableDates() && this.myService.requestDataB(), 
    {allowSignalWrites: true}
);

  handleSelectDates(dates: Dates) {
    this.myService.selectedDates.set(dates);
  }
}
```

Service:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ExampleService {
  #http = inject(HttpClient)
  #someOtherService = inject(SomeOtherServiceService)

  exampleState = signal({state: []})
  selectedDates = signal(start: null, end: null})

  availableDates = computed(() => this.#someOtherService.dataAdates())

  #setInitDates = effect(
    () => 
      this.availableDates() && this.selectedDates.set(this.availableDates()),
    { allowSignalWrites: true }
  );

  requestData() {
    this.#http.get('url').subscribe(data => this.exampleState.set({state: data}))
  }
}
```

I know the Angular team advises against the use of `{allowSignalWrites: true}` but any other way I can think of even using rxjs, storing the response to the service would be a side-effect, like:

```
waitForA = toObservable(this.myService.availableDates())
  .subscribe(dates => dates && this.myService.requestDataB()
);
```

Comment: why isn't `selectedDates` a computed signal ?

Comment: looks like you need to read this about effects https://angular.dev/guide/signals#use-cases-for-effects cause you are abusing them. In your case you can computed like @MatthieuRiegler suggests.

Comment: You're right. The example was missing the case where the user has to input a date range. I've edited the code to reflect it.